# ravendb linq query does not use overriden equals method?

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb, hashcode, equality

This works :

```
IQueryable<Record> query = _db.Query<Record>()
                .Statistics(out stats)
                .Where(r => r.Keywords.Any(
                 k => k.Value.Equals(searchInputModel.Keyword.Value)));
```

but this doesn't

```
 IQueryable<Record> queryBorked = _db.Query<Record>()
                .Statistics(out stats)
                .Where(r => r.Keywords.Any(
                k => k.Equals(searchInputModel.Keyword)));
```

even though I have overridden equals and hashcode for the Keyword class like below, so only value is checked for equality :

```
protected bool Equals(Keyword other)
        {
            return string.Equals(Value, other.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {

            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
            return Equals((Keyword) obj);
        }
```

And hashcode :

```
public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return (Value.ToLower().GetHashCode() * 397);
                //return (Value.ToLower().GetHashCode()*397) ^ Vocab.ToLower().GetHashCode();
            }
        }
```

Does ravendb use a different equality check ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RavenDB uses it's own Linq-like implementation on the database side (Query returns an IRavenQueryable instead of a "normal" .NET Queryable object), therefore it is not possible to use the overridden implementation as such in your query.

The following would work:

```
IQueryable<Record> queryBorked = _db.Query<Record>()
            .Statistics(out stats)
            .ToList()
            .Where(r => r.Keywords.Any(
            k => k.Equals(searchInputModel.Keyword)));
```

Notice the "ToList()". This will return the results of all records which you can then further reduce using the .NET Linq implementation and therefore also your overriden Equals implementation.

Do note however, that this will return all the record data from the database and that YOU are reducing the data further in code using the where-clause. Whereas your first, working, example would perform the where-clause in the database and only return the reduced set of record results to you.

Comment: is that documented anywhere ?

Comment: Not as such, but here:

[link](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/using-linq-to-query-ravendb)

It does mention limited Linq support.

Comment: Any IQueryable is dependent upon turning your expression tree into a query that gets sent to the provider of that query. This is fundamental to using LINQ-to-(something remote) instead of LINQ-to-Objects, and does not have anything to do specifically with RavenDB. You'd see the same thing with Entity Framework or an OData queryable.